# how to prevent MongoTransactionError: Transaction already in progress

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, transactions, aggregation-framework

In the server of my app, I have several routes using transactions:

```
      await mongo_tran_ses.withTransaction(async () => {
        ....
      }, tran_option);
```

If a request comes in to a route using a transaction while another transaction is still taking place, this error occurs:

```
MongoTransactionError: Transaction already in progress
```

Instead of erroring out, how do I get it wait until the first transaction completes?

EDITED:

"mongodb": "^4.13.0",

Comment: Create different sessions and transactions for each request